# Extracting shapefile vertices & attribute table information using Python

Tags: arcpy, csv, fields-attributes, vertices

I have a python script( not mine) which works fine. It extracts the vertex points from a shapefile in Arcmap and produces a CSV file with the following information.

- OID
- Sequence_id
- x_coordinate
- y_coordinate

What I am looking to do is also add onto this script a way to extract certain fields from the attribute table into the CSV file.

For instance, I would like to extract the 'Name' attribute information that corresponds to each vertex point extracted.

This is the current script:

```
import os
import csv
import arcpy
from os import path
from arcpy import da
from arcpy import env

env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = 'Folderlocation'

polygon_shp = path.join(env.workspace, 'shapefilelocation.shp')
vertex_csv_path = 'CSVpath.csv'

def getPolygonCoordinates(fc):
"""For each polygon geometry in a shapefile get the sequence number and
and coordinates of each vertex and tie it to the OID of its corresponding
polygon"""

vtx_dict = {}
s_fields = ['OID@', 'Shape@XY']
pt_array = da.FeatureClassToNumPyArray(polygon_shp, s_fields, 
    explode_to_points=True)

for oid, xy in pt_array:
    xy_tup = tuple(xy)
    if oid not in vtx_dict:
        vtx_dict[oid] = [xy_tup]
    # this clause ensures that the first/last point which is listed
    # twice only appears in the list once
    elif xy_tup not in vtx_dict[oid]:
        vtx_dict[oid].append(xy_tup)



vtx_sheet = []
for oid, vtx_list in vtx_dict.iteritems():
    for i, vtx in enumerate(vtx_list):
        vtx_sheet.append((oid, i, vtx[0], vtx[1]))

writeVerticesToCsv(vtx_sheet)

def writeVerticesToCsv(vtx_sheet):
"""Write polygon vertex information to csv"""

header = (
    'oid',          'sequence_id', 
    'x_coordinate', 'y_coordinate',)

with open(vertex_csv_path, 'wb') as vtx_csv:
    vtx_writer = csv.writer(vtx_csv)
    vtx_writer.writerow(header)

    for row in vtx_sheet:
        vtx_writer.writerow(row)

getPolygonCoordinates(polygon_shp)
```

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.  What do you mean by *extract the 'Name' attribute information*?  Where is this *Name* attribute found?  Is there a field in your Shapefile called "Name"?  Please [edit] your question to include any extra information or clarification.  A sample of your data may be useful, and details about the type of shapefile (point, line, polygon)

Comment: You have shown us code that you say works but where is a code snippet that illustrates what you have tried and where you are stuck with how "to extract certain fields from the attribute table into the CSV file"?  At the moment it looks like you are saying you have code and you want our community to enhance it for you rather than you trying to enhance it and then asking a focussed question about where you are stuck.

Comment: Sorry, still figuring this all out, I'll amend my original question and provide an example

Comment: 3 out of the box tools will accomplish this: a) feature vertices to points; b) add geometry attributes c) table to Excel.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done very simply with arcpy using [the example](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001t000000) on how to read polygon geometries with a cursor with a few minor changes:

```
import os, sys, arcpy

env.overwriteOutput = True
env.workspace = 'Folderlocation'
polygon_shp = path.join(env.workspace, 'shapefilelocation.shp')
vertex_csv_path = 'CSVpath.csv'

# do some tests...
d = arcpy.Describe(polygon_shp)
if !d.hasOID:
    arcpy.AddError("No OID/FID field")
    sys.exit(-1)
OID_Field = d.OIDFieldName # get the OID/FID field name http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#/Table_properties/03q300000050000000/

if d.shapeType != 'Polygon':
    arcpy.AddError("Polygon Shape is not a polygon")
    sys.exit(-2)

flds = arcpy.ListFields(polygon_shp,"Sequence_id")
if len(flds) == 0:
    arcpy.AddError("Expected field 'sequence_id' not found")
    sys.exit(-3)

# do the work..
with open(vertex_csv_path,'w') as CSVwrite:
    CSVwrite.write("{},sequence_id,x_coordinate,y_coordinate\n".format(OID_Field))
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(polygon_shp,[OID_Field,"SHAPE@","Sequence_id"]) as SCur:
        for ThisFeat in SCur:
            OID_value = ThisFeat[0]
            SequenceID= ThisFeat[2]
            for part in ThisFeat[1]: # see example http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//002z0000001t000000
                for pnt in part:
                    CSVwrite.write("{},{},{},{}\n".format(OID_value,SequenceID,pnt.X,pnt.Y))
```

This helps if you don't have an advanced license to use Feature Vertices to Points tool.